# callback function attached to window event not executed after opening the iOS Control Center

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic3, cordova-plugins

In my ionic application for IOS I am listening to a window event generated by a cordova plugin.
Here is the code that I use for listen to the event and perform an action.

```
window.addEventListener('event', (event) => {
            ...
                console.log("event received");

            doSomething();
          });
doSomething(){console.log("perform an action");}
```

Everything work and I am able to receive the event until I open the IOS Control Center (swipe up from the bottom). After I close the Control Center again I can see that the event is logged ("event received") but the function doSomething() is never called.
Someone encountered a similar situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the event is generated outside angular, I needed to call ngZone.run in order to let angular know that something happend and so trigger the change. I thid it this way

```
constructor(private zone: NgZone) {}

ngOnInit(){
        window.addEventListener('event', (event) => {

              this.ngZone.run(() => {
                do stuff;
              });
}
```